# Can't retrieve Nuxt3 env variables on deployment server

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js, nuxt3

As I said in the title, I can't get the env variables on Nuxt3 when the app is deployed on server. I'm running the app on Digital Ocean server and is deployed through a Dockerfile and Github Action scripts.

I'm aware that Nuxt does not read the env variables for the client side, but I thought that if I attach the envs on build time, it will work, but so far there is no success.

I will attach below all the relevant code. I have to mention that if I go inside the container, the .env file is created successfully with the correct values and also the "printenv" command will give me all the right values.

When I try to run the app in browser, I have the "invalid firebase api key" error, which is basically the sign that my variables are not read. On localhost it's working fine.

I have also prefixed the envs variables with ***NUXT_*** for private and ***NUXT_PUBLIC_*** for public ones.

I've also tried to retrieve the envs from a Nuxt endpoint (from server-side) and it's working, but then the values will be available inside network tab.

Dockerfile snippet:

```
   FROM node:alpine AS base

   WORKDIR /code

ARG NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY
ENV NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY
RUN echo "NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY" >> /code/.env

<other envs here>

# Stage 2 - builder
FROM base AS builder

WORKDIR /code

COPY package*.json ./

COPY ./ ./

COPY --from=base /code/.env /code/.env

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

# Stage 3 - run
FROM base AS final

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    git \
    wget curl \
    nginx \
    supervisor

WORKDIR /code

ADD package.json ./
ADD nuxt.config.ts ./
ADD .docker/nuxt/nginx-app.conf ./

COPY --from=builder /code/.output /code/.output
COPY --from=builder /code/node_modules /code/node_modules
COPY --from=builder /code/.env /code/.env

RUN \
    # copy nginx site config \
    mv ./nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", ".output/server/index.mjs" ]
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```
runtimeConfig: {
    FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
    FIREBASE_APP_ID: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: process.env.NUXT_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    public: {
      BASE_URL_API: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_API,
      HOST: '0.0.0.0'
    }
```

Docker command:

```
run: >
          docker build --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON=$(echo $FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$(echo $FIREBASE_API_KEY) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$(echo $FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$(echo $FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=$(echo $FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID=$(echo $FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_APP_ID=$(echo $FIREBASE_APP_ID) 
          --build-arg NUXT_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=$(echo $FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID) 
          --build-arg NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_API=$(echo $BASE_URL_API) 
          -t $(echo $REGISTRY)/$(echo $IMAGE_NAME):$(echo $REF-$(echo $SHA | head -c7)) -f .docker/nuxt/Dockerfile .
```

run command:

```
docker run -d \
            -p 3030:3000 \
            --restart always \
            --name $(echo $IMAGE_NAME) $(echo $REGISTRY)/$(echo $IMAGE_NAME):$(echo $REF-$(echo $SHA | head -c7))
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem @Laurentiu Amazerscu -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76978604/runtime-loading-operating-system-variable-in-nuxt-3

Did you managed with this problem?