# Runtime loading operating system variable in Nuxt 3

Tags: environment-variables, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a problem  with injecting my operating system variable into SSR Nuxt 3 application. When I run in locally then variable from .env file is loaded correctly. But when I deploy application in AWS linux container then the variable is not injecting.

Preconditions:

1. I have set my variable using terraform(and I know it is set properly, because I can read it in other way)

```
 NUXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY = "XYZ"
```

2. Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run generate

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=builder-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

3. nuxt.config.ts looks like

```
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            secretKey: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY 
        }
    },
```

But when i try to console.log it.. it is not loaded, console log draws *undefined*

```
console.log("Secret key is", useRuntimeConfig().public.secretKey)
```

As I understand correctly, it should be possible, [documentation says](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#environment-variables):

```
Nuxi CLI has built-in support for reading your .env file in development, build and generate. But when you run your built server, your .env file will not be read.
```

so it should load it from operating system environments?

UPDATE:
I tried to figure out how is going on.. And it is weird.. when i set variable in builder-stage - it works, variable can be read by nuxt 3, but when i try to set variable in production-stage it doesn't work..

WORKS

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder-stage
ENV NUXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY sectretkeyBulderStage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run generate

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=builder-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run generate

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
ENV NUXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY sectretkeyProductionStage
COPY --from=builder-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```